# Joi invalidate a range of numbers

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I am trying to support decimal values for a field but I would like to prevent an inclusive range of numbers.

Expected Validity:

```
x<=1 || x>=1
```

So basically, I want to invalidate range `[-1,1]`. Currently, I have this snippet but needs some help.

```
Joi.number().required()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) with [.less](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) and [.greater](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#numbergreaterlimit):

```
Joi.object({
  number: Joi.number().required()
}).when(
  Joi.object({ number: Joi.number().greater(-1).less(1)  }).unknown(), 
  { then: Joi.object({ number: Joi.forbidden() }) }
)
```

When `number` contains a value between `[-1,1]` then it will be forbidden.

Here's some results:

```
{ number: 0.9 }   // Validation Error: "number" is not allowed
{ number: 0 }     // Validation Error: "number" is not allowed
{ number: -0.3 }  // Validation Error: "number" is not allowed
{ number: 1 }     // Validation Passed
{ number: -1 }    // Validation Passed
{ number: -13 }   // Validation Passed
```